# Add average grade to Google Maps route (i.e. slope)

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-maps, math

I have this function that outputs the total elevation gain and drop during a specific route.  I would also like to export the average grade (i.e. slope) of the segment.   Do I use the equation m = rise/run ?  How would I go about implementing this?

```
var writeStats = function(r) {
  var prevElevation = r[0].elevation;
  var climb = 0;
  var drop = 0;
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
    var diff = r[i].elevation - prevElevation;
    prevElevation = r[i].elevation;
    if (diff > 0) {
      climb += diff;
      climb = Math.abs(climb / 1) ;//Object to number
      var  climb2 = climb  * 3.2808399;//Metres to feet

    }
    else {
      drop -= diff;
      drop = Math.abs(drop / 1) ;
      var  drop2 = drop  * 3.2808399;

    }

    if (r[i].elevation > max) {
      max = r[i].elevation;
    }
  }
  max = Math.ceil(max);
  $('#climb-drop').text("Climb: " + Math.round(climb2) + " feet Drop: " + Math.round(drop2) + " feet");
  return max;
};
```

**UPDATE**: I would like to tie this into the function that calculates the route:

```
var from = new google.maps.LatLng(40.750484, -111.811177);
var to = new google.maps.LatLng(40.775041, -111.718560);

     ds.route({
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    }, function(result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          fitBounds = true;
          dr.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Elevation chart for route(s) from the DirectionsService](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_elevation-profile_distance.html)

Answer (score 0):

It appears from this article (http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm) that you can use `getElevationByLocations` to do this.

This is the main part, but you may want to read through the code to see how to use it:

```
elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) 
{
if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) 
{
// Retrieve the first result
if (results[0]) 
{
// Open an info window indicating the elevation at the clicked position
outputDiv.innerHTML= "Last point clicked : " + results[0].elevation.toFixed(3) + " m";
```

Here is the documentation for this function:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation

So, just determine the elevation at each marker, then use your formula to get the elevation change, but make certain to point out that this is an average as it could change a great deal in-between two points and still look, on average, to be flat.

Comment: @James--see my update, is this possible to tie this into the route request?

Comment: I don't believe it is, but if you just loop over your waypoints you should be able to figure it out.